# Amazon Connect Agent Event Streams - Sending data to SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-connect, amazon-kinesis

Is there a way to send the data from a Kinesis Data Firehose Delivery Stream that uses the Agent Event Streams to an SNS topic which then triggers a lambda? I know you can send data from SNS to firehose via subscribing a topic to it, but what about vice versa?

Currently I have a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream setup that sends data to S3, and my goal is to use this data to trigger a lambda that will then a message to SNS and then Microsoft teams...any help or just general direction would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not without custom lambda.
But if you’re interested in Contact events, then you can subscribe to Event Bridge and route those events to SNS.